# Probability: Balls in baskets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning

I'm self learning and I stumbled upon the following exercise but I'm not sure if I solved it correct as I'm very new to this.

Problem: 7 balls fall independently into 7 baskets. Let $X_i$ = number of baskets containing $i$ balls. What is the distribution of $X_3$?

Solution:

$A$ = $\{$ Basket contains 3 balls $\}$

$B_j$ = $\{$ A ball falls into basket $j$ $\};j=1,2...7$

$P(B_j) = \frac17$

$P(A) = \binom73 P(B_j)^3P(\overline B_j)^4 = 35\cdot \frac17^3(1-\frac17)^4 = \frac{5\cdot 6^4}{7^6}$

Is this correct so far? I was wondering whether I should multiply the above by 7 since $j$ can be positioned in 7 different combinations but I concluded that since the event $B_j$ doesn't specify that there are other baskets (can be understood as if a ball either goes into basket $j$ or not at all) so I didn't do it. Is that correct?

Now the distribution:

$P(X_3 = 0) = \binom 70 P(A)^0P(\overline A)^7$

$P(X_3 = 1) = \binom 71 P(A)^1P(\overline A)^6$

$P(X_3 = 2) = \binom 72 P(A)^2P(\overline A)^5$

$P(X_3 = 3) = \binom 73 P(A)^3P(\overline A)^4 =N/A$ since $3\cdot 3 > 7$

$P(X_3 = 4) = \binom 74 P(A)^4P(\overline A)^3 =N/A$ since $4\cdot 3 > 7$

$P(X_3 = 5) = \binom 75 P(A)^5P(\overline A)^2 =N/A$ since $5\cdot 3 > 7$

$P(X_3 = 6) = \binom 76 P(A)^6P(\overline A)^1 =N/A$ since $6\cdot 3 > 7$

$P(X_3 = 7) = \binom 77 P(A)^7P(\overline A)^0 =N/A$ since $7\cdot 3 > 7$

Is this correct?

What is the expected way to prove that from $X_3$ to $X_7$ it's N/A if this was on an exam? Do I even have to write these cases into the table?

Comment: Well the last $5$ have a probability of $0$ (since it's not possible to happen).  You can check your work because the first three had better add up to $1$ since there are definitely either $0$ baskets with three balls, $1$ basket, or $2$ (not possible for there to be more).  I also suspect you are going about this incorrectly.  For instance, $P(X_3 = 0)$ would be the probability that each basket has $0$, $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $6$ or $7$ balls in it (there are _lots_ of ways for that to happen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $P(X_3=2),\;$ for instance there is only one possible **pattern,**

and we can compute number of ways as [Choose baskets for placing] $\times\;$[Place balls in baskets]

$3-3-1-0-0-0-0:\;\left[\binom72\binom51 \right] \times \frac{7!}{3!3!}=14,700$

You can similarly find out for $X_3 = 0,\;$and $\;X_3=1.\; X_3>2$ will obviously have zero ways

Finally you can complete the probability distribution by dividing by $\;7^7\;$for each case

---

**ADDED**: Patterns for other cases

$X=0$: 7-0-0-0-0-0-0 | 6-1-0-0-0-0-0 | 5-2-0-0-0-0-0 | 5-1-1-0-0-0-0 | 4-2-1-0-0-0-0 | 4-1-1-1-0-0-0 | 2-2-2-1-0-0-0 | 2-2-1-1-1-0-0 | 2-1-1-1-1-1-0 | and 1-1-1-1-1-1-1

$X=1$: 3-2-2-0-0-0-0 | 3-2-1-1-0-0-0 | and 3-1-1-1-1-0-0

*PS:*

As pointed out by Graham Kemp, you needn't actually compute P(X=0), instead you can find it using the complement. But if you want to be *sure* that you haven't made any computational error, you will need to compute it and check that the probabilities add up to $1$.

Comment: Could you give a bit more details. I don't understand why you multiply by $\frac{7!}{3!3!}$. How would this work for the other cases?

Comment: Multiplying by $\frac{7!}{3!3!}$ is simply to take care of possible permutations of the $3-3-1-0-0-0-0$ pattern. I'll add patterns for other cases in the answer.

Comment: $\frac{7!}{3!3!}$, or in full, $\frac{7!}{3!3!1!}$ is simply using the permutation formula where some objects are identical, that's why the denominator.

Comment: So if I understood correctly for the first pattern of it is $X = 0: [\binom 73 \binom 71]*\frac{7!}{2!2!2!1!}$?

Comment: Not quite. The first term will be $\binom73\binom41$ , reflecting that after you have chosen the $3$ baskets, with $2$ each, there are only $4$ baskets left from which to choose the one with $1$ ball.

Comment: PS:  $X_3=0$ *also* includes patterns `4-1-1-1-0-0-0`, `4-2-1-0-0-0-0`, `5-1-1-0-0-0-0`, `5-2-0-0-0-0-0`, `6-1-0-0-0-0-0`, and `7-0-0-0-0-0-0`.

Comment: Why $X=1$ includes 3-2-1-1-0-0-0 twice? Did you mean 3-4-0-0-0-0-0?

Comment: That was a typo. I will delete it, also include missed patterns!

Comment: @GrahamKemp: My bad, thanks for pointing out . In very bad form, it seems !

Answer (score 0):

As true blue anil stated, the counting method is to count ways to sort balls into a pattern times the permutations of that pattern.

I suggest using multinomial coefficients† to ensure your counting logic matches up.   For instance: the event $X_3=2$ can be satisfied by any pattern of 3 balls in each of two boxes and one ball in another.   First we count ways to assign balls to boxes in that pattern, then ways to arrange the boxes; all divided by $7^7$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_3=2) =&~ 7^{-7}{\tbinom{7}{3,3,1\color{silver}{,0,0,0,0}}\tbinom{7}{2,1,4}}
\\[1ex] =&~ 7^{-7}\tbinom{7}{3}\tbinom{4}{3}\tbinom{7}{2}\tbinom{5}{1}
\\[1ex] =&~ \tfrac{6!^2}{7^5~3!^2~2!}
\end{align}$$

Note: the additional zeroes are redundant, and included only to demonstrate that the pattern contains four empty boxes.

Similarly we build the probability for $X_3=1$:

$$\begin{align} \mathsf P(X_3=1) =&~ 7^{-7}\left(\tbinom{7}{3,1,1,1,1\color{silver}{,0,0}}\tbinom{7}{1,4,2}+\tbinom{7}{3,2,1,1\color{silver}{,0,0,0}}\tbinom{7}{1,1,2,3}+\tbinom{7}{3,2,2\color{silver}{,0,0,0,0}}\tbinom{7}{1,2,4}+\tbinom{7}{3,4\color{silver}{,0,0,0,0,0}}\tbinom{7}{1,1,5}\right)
\\[1ex] =&~ \tfrac{6!^2}{3!~7^5}\left(\tfrac{1}{4!~2!}+\tfrac{1}{3!~2!^2}+\tfrac{1}{2!^3~4!}+\tfrac{1}{4!~5!}\right)
\end{align}$$

We *could* do the same for $X_3=0$, however there are many more possible patterns and it is easier to just note that it is the complement of the union of the above two events.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_3 = 0) =&~ 1-\mathsf P(X_3=1)-\mathsf P(X_3=2)
\end{align}$$

---

† The multinomial coefficient is: $\dbinom{x+y+z+\ldots}{x,y,z,\ldots} = \dfrac{(x+y+z+\ldots)!}{x!~y!~z!~\cdots} = \dbinom{x+y+z+\ldots}{x}\dbinom{y+z+\ldots}{y}\dbinom{z+\ldots}{z}\cdots$